# Big o notation of java function

Tags: java, big-o

I want to calculate Big o of a function I need to make at school, but after a lot of research I cant calculate it accurately.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MainClass main = new MainClass();

        // This test should return false message
        Boolean test = main.verificationMessage("Maxime", "eeeeemmiiabcdefodofrjvozomixam");

        if (test) {
            System.out.println("Message OK");
        } else {
            System.out.println("The enemy is at the door");
        }

        // This test should return true message
        test = main.verificationMessage("Maxime", "axemiMakkoepviivjsobcgdteryid");

        if (test) {
            System.out.println("Message OK");
        } else {
            System.out.println("The enemy is at the door");
        }
        
        // This test should return false message
        test = main.verificationMessage("Maxime", "axemi");

        if (test) {
            System.out.println("Message OK");
        } else {
            System.out.println("The enemy is at the door");
        }

    }

    public boolean verificationMessage(String message, String lettersFinded) {
        //If lettersFinded < message, then we didn't have to do anything, we know it's a false message
        if(lettersFinded.length() >= message.length()){
            HashMap<Character, Integer> occurenceMessage = new HashMap<>();
            HashMap<Character, Integer> occurenceLetters = new HashMap<>();

            makeMaps(message, occurenceMessage);
            makeMaps(lettersFinded, occurenceLetters);

            for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : occurenceMessage.entrySet()) {
                // If a letter of the message map is not present or not found enought times
                // in lettersFinded, then return false
                if (occurenceLetters.getOrDefault(entry.getKey(), 0) < entry.getValue()){
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
        
    }

    // Create a hashmap to define the number of occurences of each character in the two strings
    public void makeMaps(String s, HashMap<Character, Integer> map) {
        for (char ch : s.toCharArray()) {
            if (ch != ' ') {
                if (map.containsKey(ch)) {
                    // If char is present in charCountMap, incrementing it's count by 1
                    map.put(ch, map.get(ch) + 1);
                } else {
                    // If char is not present in map putting this char to map with 1 as it's value
                    map.put(ch, 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This is a simple function that compare two strings and verify that you can make the message with the lettersFinded.

Makemaps count the occurence of each char of the string and put it in the hashmap.

For example :

"Tesst" --> [T,1 ; e,1 ; s,2 ; t,1]

My idea is that it was Big o = O(n) where n equals message.length() because I iterate in the hasmap exactly n times, but I think that i'm wrong.

Does anybody know how to do it ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What does `makeMaps` do? Without that information we can only guess.

Comment: Assuming you don't have any zero values in your `occurrence*` maps, the two return conditions can be written as one: `if (occurenceLetters.getOrDefault(entry.getKey(), 0) < entry.getValue())`.

Comment: Ok thank you @AndyTurner. I just updated the code.
So like it's now, what would be my bigO notation ?

Comment: So assuming n = message.length() and m = lettersFound.length(), it would be :
O(max(N,M)) ?

Comment: I'd say it's `O(n + m)`. It's also `O(max(n, m))`, but that's not as tight a bound (since `n + m <= 2 * max(n, m)`).

Comment: Ok thank you very much. And if I have tu justificate it, could I say that its O(n+m) beacause it iterate N times at a minimum and M times at a maximum, so in the worst case it would be O( n + m) ?

Comment: Actually, it iterates _both_ the strings to count the characters, then iterates the _unique_ chars in the message again, to check the counts, so it's always O(n+m) (or O(2n+m), which is the same thing)